# Change priority of different aliases with the same aliases

Tags: path-aliases, 9

There is vocabulary, let's call it forum tags which contain all forum tags,
Also, in Forum, the link for the Forum container using a similar tag pattern for the forums.
for example,

```
Term name : windows
term alias: /forum/windows

Forum container: windows
forum alias:     /forum/windows
```

if I open `/forum/windows` always term page will be loaded which means it has a higher priority.

at the moment all request handled by taxonomy handler which shows term page.

any thoughts on how can change the aliases priority?

(there are some other solutions to achieve what I'm doing without the same aliases but I'm wondering how we can do this on Drupal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forum shown on /admin/structure/forum/add/container (to create a forum container) or on /admin/structure/forum/add/forum (to create a forum) is the form to create a taxonomy term.

In fact, the controller method called for /admin/structure/forum/add/container ([ForumController::addContainer()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21src%21Controller%21ForumController.php/function/ForumController%3A%3AaddContainer/9.2.x)) contains the following code.

```php
$vid = $this->config('forum.settings')->get('vocabulary');
$taxonomy_term = $this->termStorage->create([
  'vid' => $vid,
  'forum_container' => 1,
]);

return $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($taxonomy_term, 'container');
```

There aren't two path aliases: There is only a taxonomy term path alias shown in two different pages that allow to edit it.
This is could be confusing, as /admin/structure/forum/add/container (and /admin/structure/forum/add/forum) doesn't give any hint that the submitted data are for a taxonomy term.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. 
and the moment problem is term path alias has priority rather than forum container.

Comment: There are just path aliases for taxonomy terms; there aren't path alias for forums or forum containers. This means there isn't a path alias that takes precedence other another one, in this case.

Comment: I just double check it. that's right, the problem is on my views which I know how can handle it. 
thank you